# Indentificar 3 resultados iguais em 3 BD mysql diferentes

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

tenho um aplicativo em php que criei que listo vários ips, em alguns sites que uso, eu gostaria de listar os ips iguais em 3 sites numa unica lista! Como Faço?

Maior Problema:
As tabelas dos bancos de dados possuem o mesmo nome, só os bancos que não. Estão todos no meu servidor. mas domínios diferentes.

Comment: Monta um array que agrupa os ips de todos os bancos.

Answer (score 0):

Algumas opções:

1 Assumindo que você tem um usuário que tem acesso aos 3 bancos de dados (no mesmo servidor). Então, faz uma query com INNER JOIN buscando IPs que ocorrem nos 3 bancos.

```
SELECT *
FROM db1.tabela_ips AS a
INNER JOIN db2.tabela_ips b ON a.num_ip = b.num_ip
INNER JOIN db3.tabela_ips c ON b.num_ip = c.num_ip
```

Nesse caso, apenas os IPs que ocorrem nos 3 bancos serão exibidos.

2 Partindo da mesma premissa anterior, essa query gera uma lista única com todos os dados e então remove os itens duplicados.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip 
FROM (
SELECT * FROM db1.tabela_ips
UNION
SELECT * FROM db2.tabela_ips
UNION
SELECT * FROM db3.tabela_ips
) t
```

3 Se cada banco tem um usuário exclusivo, então você faz um script PHP que conecta e busca os dados dos 3 bancos e então usa uma função `array_merge` para unir as 3 listas e excluir os duplicados (como no caso 2).